# How can i make an image in navbar be affcted on hover

Tags: html, css

i am trying to learn how to make hover on image in
navbar
my goal is to make the div-image **"pic-index"** to be
affcted by hover on **"HOME"** link in navbar and make the div to be
changed into another image by hover .
i really dont have any idea
how i can do such thing .
here is my **HTML** :

I added an snippet to my question, so you can see what I current have in my code

```css
     
        
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: white;
    }
    
    .nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .logo{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1136px;
    margin-top:-3px;
    }
    
    .mainul {
      height: 145px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #7e7e7ea6;
    }
    
    .mainul2{
        
      height: 145px;
      box-shadow: 5px 9px 29px -2px #0000005e;
    }
    
    .pic-index{
        
        position:absolute;margin-left:936px;margin-top:62px;
    }
    .nav li {
      font-family: Varela Round;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-align: left;
        padding-right:;
    }
    
    .nav a {
      font-size:15px;
      margin-top:50px;
      margin-left:20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #5a5a5a;
      display: block;
      padding-left: 15px;
    
      transition: .3s background-color;
    }
    
    .nav a:hover {
     color:#57c0ea;
    }
    
    .nav a.active {
      
      color: #444;
      cursor: default;
    }
    
    /* Sub Menus */
    .nav li li {
      font-size: .8em;
    }
    
    /*******************************************
       Style menu for larger screens
    
       Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
       or other values could be used depending on other factors
    ********************************************/
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
      .nav li {
        width: 130px;
        border-bottom: none;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: -4px;
      }
    
      .nav a {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
    
      .nav > ul > li {
        text-align: center;
      }
    
      .nav > ul > li > a {
        padding-left: 0;
      }
    
      /* Sub Menus */
      .nav li ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: inherit;
      }
    
      .nav li:hover ul {
        display: block;
      }
    
      .nav li ul li {
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="nav"> <ul class="mainul"> <ul class="mainul2">
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/Logo-1.png"></div>
        <div class="pic-index"><img src="images/nav-home-normal.png"></div> <li class="contact"><a href="#">צור קשר</a> <ul>
    
    </ul> </li> <li class="services"><a href="#">שירותים</a> <ul> <li><a href="#">Tutorial #1@@</a></li> <li><a href="#">Tutorial #2</a></li> <li><a href="#">Tutorial #3</a></li> </ul> </li>
         <li class="about"><a href="#">אודות</a>
    
    </li> <li class="home"><a href="#">דף הבית</a></li>
        </ul> </ul> </div>
```

Comment: Write the example on jsfiddle or jsbin or codepen

Comment: https://codepen.io/cpsplayed123/pen/VQKZjm

Hi , 
im trying to make the HOME ICON to be affcted  when hover on HOME LINK and be changed into another image ,

Comment: Images are broken, use absolute URLs

Comment: You need to use JQuery for this

Comment: thats great can you send me an code how can i do that with JQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your `.home` is after the `.pic-index` you only can achieve that with some JS or jQuery, here's a solution with jQuery.
If `.pic-index` comes before `.home`, then you would be able to use only CSS, but it's not the case.
**(I Added an image just to represent the effect, run the snippet in FULLSCREEN to better visualization)**

**EDIT**
Another thing, I made a small update in the css, but it's up for you to keep it or no (added css to img class).
ALSO, you have some HTML structure errors in the lists, some `ul` and `li` starts and ends on wrong places

```js
/* HOVER */
$(function() {

  $('.home').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.pic-index img').attr(
    'src', 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/sign-check-icon.png'
    );
  });
  
  $('.home').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.pic-index img').attr(
    'src', 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/256/Actions-help-about-icon.png'
    );
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: white;
    }
    
    .nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .logo{
      position: absolute;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 1136px;
      margin-top:-3px;
    }
    
    .mainul {
      height: 145px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #7e7e7ea6;
    }
    
    .mainul2{        
      height: 145px;
      box-shadow: 5px 9px 29px -2px #0000005e;
    }
    
    .pic-index{        
        position:relative;
        top:30%;
        float: right;   
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
    .pic-index img{
        max-width: 48px;
        max-height: 48px;        
    }
    
    .nav li {
      font-family: Varela Round;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-align: left;
        padding-right:;
    }
    
    .nav a {
      font-size:15px;
      margin-top:50px;
      margin-left:20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #5a5a5a;
      display: block;
      padding-left: 15px;
    
      transition: .3s background-color;
    }
    
    .nav a:hover {
     color:#57c0ea;
    }
    
    .nav a.active {
      
      color: #444;
      cursor: default;
    }
    
    /* Sub Menus */
    .nav li li {
      font-size: .8em;
    }
    

    
    /*******************************************
       Style menu for larger screens
    
       Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
       or other values could be used depending on other factors
    ********************************************/
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
      .nav li {
        width: 130px;
        border-bottom: none;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: -4px;
      }
    
      .nav a {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
    
      .nav > ul > li {
        text-align: center;
      }
    
      .nav > ul > li > a {
        padding-left: 0;
      }
    
      /* Sub Menus */
      .nav li ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: inherit;
      }
    
      .nav li:hover ul {
        display: block;
      }
    
      .nav li ul li {
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
   <div class="nav"> <ul class="mainul"> 
   <ul class="mainul2">
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/Logo-1.png"></div>
        <div class="pic-index"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/256/Actions-help-about-icon.png"></div> 
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">צור קשר</a>
        <ul>
     </li>
    </ul>  
    <li class="services"><a href="#">שירותים</a>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Tutorial #1@@</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorial #2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorial #3</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    </li>
         <li class="about"><a href="#">אודות</a></li>
         <li class="home"><a href="#">דף הבית</a></li>
      </ul>       
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks this is it ,
but i am trying to use image instad but cant do that what i do wrong ?
    /* HOVER */
$(function() {
  $('.home').hover(function() {
    $('.pic-index').css('opacity', '0.4');
    $('.pic-index').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/CEmBNVi.png');
  }, function() {
    $('.pic-index').css('opacity', '1.0');
   $('.pic-index').attr('src', '/images/nav-home-normal.png');
  });
});

Comment: I edited the answer, there was an error, now it's working perfectly. If this helps you, please mark as correct and upvote :D